# How can I know current animation in CAAnimationGroups?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

Now I want to use Core Animation to write some methods for animation just as easy as Cocos2d ,just like `ccMove`,`ccFade`,`ccRotate`.

Everything seems ok, but when I want to implement the animation sequence,I've troubled.The first thing I've thought was `CCAnimationGroup`,but when animations in groups,I can not kown when the current action complete, so I can't set the property of layer, this lead to the layer back to the original status. Anyone know this ? My code:

```
    UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    testView.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
    testView.center = self.view.center;
    //mark1: textview's position is self.view.center
    [self.view addSubview:testView];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation 
        animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnimation.duration = 3;
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 200, 200);
    moveAnimation.path = path;
    //mark2: I want the testview move to CGPointMake(100,200)
    CGPathRelease(path);   

    CABasicAnimation *angleAnimation = 
        [CABasicAnimation 
          animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    angleAnimation.toValue = @(45 * M_PI / 180);
    angleAnimation.duration = 3;
    angleAnimation.beginTime = 3;  //make3: rotate testview 45°

    CAAnimationGroup *actionGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    [actionGroup setDuration:6];
    [actionGroup setAnimations:@[moveAnimation, angleAnimation]];

    [CATransaction begin];

    [testView.layer addAnimation:actionGroup forKey:nil];

    [CATransaction commit];
```

You can run it, and you'll see the textview's position and rotate is not I want.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it.In fact,I don't need to know when one of the actions in group complete.Just set the animation's **fillMode** and **removedOnCompletion**, so that the the layer would not back to original status.

```
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
testView.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
testView.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:testView];   //mark1: textview's position is self.view.center

CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
moveAnimation.duration = 3;
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 200, 200);
moveAnimation.path = path;
moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
CGPathRelease(path);    //mark2: I want the testview move to CGPointMake(100,200)

CABasicAnimation *angleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
angleAnimation.toValue = @(45 * M_PI / 180);
angleAnimation.duration = 3;
angleAnimation.beginTime = 3;  //make3: rotate testview 45°
angleAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
angleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CAAnimationGroup *actionGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
[actionGroup setDuration:6];
[actionGroup setAnimations:@[moveAnimation, angleAnimation]];
actionGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
actionGroup.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[CATransaction begin];

[testView.layer addAnimation:actionGroup forKey:nil];

[CATransaction commit];
```

In code above, I set all the action's fillmode to **kCAFillModeForwards**, and **removedOnCompletion = NO**.This just work. And I also find that **scaleAnimation** and **fadeAnimation** should set their fillmode to **kCAFillModeBoth** so that the layer cannot back to original property status.

You can also check the code on my github.https://github.com/Vienta/SSAnimation Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

CAAnimationGroup is subclass of CAAnimation, so you can have a delegate of CAAnimationGroup and receive notification when animation stoped.

`- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag`

Comment: https://github.com/Vienta/SSAnimation I put the code on github.Hope you can see it and give me help. Thank you!

Comment: @Vienta You say you have solved this? If you solved it by your self, you can write your solution down and accept it. By the way, I am a Chinese too.

Comment: Thank you for remind me! I try to make the core animation methods like cocos2d's actions.Your method is right,but if use the delegate,it would be more trouble for me.And we can also use block,just like:           [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"animation complete");
    }];
    [tTarget.layer addAnimation:action forKey:nil];
    [CATransaction commit];

Comment: Funny, all of us who pay attention to this issue are chinese? Me too.

Comment: @Danny Xu ,Maybe the Chinese English.Haha